# Small annoying problem - illegal start of expression

Tags: java, string, substring

My Problem: When I enter this piece of script in jcreator, it says illegal start of expression for (public String subString). Is there another way to enter a substring?

```
public String subString;
        int beginIndex;
        int endIndex;
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question here... are you trying to get a substring of anything?

Comment: Is that within a method or a field in a class? More code context, thanks.

Comment: You say "this piece of **script**".  Are you trying to program Java or Javascript?  Are these lines appearing in the scope of a class declaration?

Comment: I think there are some core syntactic concepts you are not yet familiar with in Java. Maybe look at some [example code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#A_more_comprehensive_example) to see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you wrote this inside a method, then you must remove the `public` keyword. Visibility is assigned to class members, not local variables.

Comment: Ok that worked. but now it says variable begin index might not have been initialized. How would I fix that?

Comment: Make sure you initialize the variables if it's local
such as String subString = null;
Note that if you declared a variables in a class, it will have it's default value, String default value is null, int default value is 0. But if you declared in a method, you should  initialize it.

Comment: @Jessica, it says that because you are likely using the variable in a context that makes the IDE believe it might not be initialized. Initialize it when defining it: `int beginIndex = 0;`

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you! You all were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Let me Clear that you want to only extract substring from any string then Follwing code can help you :

```
String name="Eagle Eye";

String s1=name.subString(2,5);
```

*Output: "gle Ey"*

Here, 2 stands for Starting position and 5 for Length of substring.